# Is this an electric guitar? if so how do i make mine sound like it?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, rock

Eight seconds into this song, there is what I think is an electric guitar.  Does anyone know how to produce that sound?  Is it even an electric guitar?

Comment: this question clearly has a definitive answer. Does not look to broad to me.

Answer (score 6):

This effect is called [volume swell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9Wpzy590d8). It's achieved by fading in notes using your volume knob or a volume pedal.

Comment: You beat me to it was just about to post the same.

Comment: Just to be clear, it *is* an electric guitar, played with volume swells. And there's a touch of feedback, delay, and reverb.

Answer (score 5):

Just a bit more info on cyco130's answer : 
'Tis indeed a volume swell effect, and is an electric guitar.

The technique is to pluck the note with the volume turned down, then bring the volume in - either via a volume pedal or using the volume control on the guitar.

Some guitars make this easier because the volume control is easily reachable from where your hand would be when playing. A Fender Stratocaster is the classic example: it's easy to pluck a string then turn the volume up. Mark Knopfler of Dire Straits used this to good effect.

There are also effects which do this automatically. They detect when you have strick a note, and fade the sound in for you with settable speed - of- volume - increase.

If you'd like a cheap-but-effective example, the Zoom 505ii pedal has this built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either a guitar with volume swells, or a electric keyboard. In my experiences sounds more like a keyboard. Or some kind of synth sound (coming from a keyboard)